# O AO90 é/tem sido aplicado no Brasil?

Tags: acordo-ortográfico

Uma das supostas razões para o uso do AO90 em Portugal é o aproximar o Português Europeu ao Português do Brasil e de outros países que falem Português.

Portanto, pergunto se o AO90 tem sido aplicado no Brasil. Se sim, é possível encontrar exemplos nos jornais e em livros publicados recentemente?

Comment: Eu andei a bisbilhotar já há uns anos, e situação era a mesma que em Portugal: a nova grafia tinha sido adotada nos manuais escolares e em alguns jornais.

Comment: Posso confirmar o que as bisbilhotices de @Jacinto lhe sugeriram.  =)   De fato, no Brasil tem sido utilizada a nova grafia, para incômodo e, por vezes, irritação nossa.  Eu lembro que o uso ou não de hífen é frequente tópico de dúvida e controvérsia aqui.

Comment: Em um comentário paralelo ao anterior, o objetivo do Acordo Ortográfico não foi exatamente aproximar o conjunto linguístico dos padrões europeu e brasileiro de Português, mas somente o registro escrito da língua inclusive para os padrões africanos e asiáticos de Português.  Salvo engano meu, o AO não versou, em particular, sobre mudança de pronúncia ou de prosódia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 tem sido utilizado pelas editoras brasileiras desde 2009 (ver estes links: [Agência Brasil](http://memoria.ebc.com.br/agenciabrasil/noticia/2008-12-21/editoras-e-autores-ja-estao-se-adaptando-ao-acordo-ortografico-da-lingua-portuguesa), [Revista Exame](http://exame.abril.com.br/negocios/noticias/reforma-ortografica-so-trouxe-prejuizos-dizem-editoras)) e é comum ver em reedições de livros alguns dizeres como os seguintes: "*Grafia atualizada segundo o Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa de 1990, que entrou em vigor no Brasil em 2009*". Vale notar que mesmo entrando em vigor em 2009, somente em 2016 o acordo passou a ter caráter obrigatório (vide o [Decreto nº 6.583, de 2008](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_Ato2007-2010/2008/Decreto/D6583.htm), conforme alteração de prazo feita em 2012).

Assim como as editoras, a maioria dos jornais também adota a nova ortografia desde 2009. Esse é o caso, p.ex., da Folha de S. Paulo ("[Folha adota nova regra ortográfica no dia 1º](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff2812200812.htm)", publicado em 28 de dezembro de 2008).